# get json format in string with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string like this :

```
$string = 'Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Language: en-US-x-lvariant-USA
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{
  "valid" : true,
  "used" : true,
  "isRecycledDomain" : false
}';
```

And now i want to match `"used" : true,` in that variable. I tried preg_match with this pattern but still not working.

```
if (preg_match('~\b\"used\" : true,\b~', $string)) {
    //word matched!
} else {
    //not found
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fix the string, do that..

Else its json with HTTP header which has a standard of 2 new lines then is body which you can split and decode the json into a workable array with a couple of lines.

```
<?php
$string = 'Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Language: en-US-x-lvariant-USA
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{
  "valid" : true,
  "used" : true,
  "isRecycledDomain" : false
}';

$string = explode("\n\n", $string, 2)[1];

$array = json_decode($string, true);

echo $array['valid'];
```

Comment: I would suggest `explode("\n\n", $string, 2)` to cover the case that the JSON is badly-formatted and itself contains a double line break.

Comment: thanks, yeah cant hurt, is abit xy, http client should return without headers

Comment: thanks @LawrenceCherone.. i decided to return without headers so the process to get json data is simpler